# Getting runtime error when i access (table->array[i][i]).min = (table->array[i][i]).max = arr[i];

Tags: c, malloc, structure, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using DP to fill a table which contains maximum & minimum item from index i to index j in an array. Whether this approach is efficient or not, is not an issue to me.
Consider the below code snippet:

```
typedef struct Slot
{
    int min;
    int max;
}Slot;

typedef struct Table
{
    Slot* *array;
    int size;
}Table;

Table* createTable( int size )
{
    Table* table = malloc( sizeof( Table ) );

    if( !table )
            return NULL;

    table->array = ( Slot(*)[size] ) malloc( size * size * sizeof( Slot ) );

    if( !(table->array) )
                    return NULL;

    table->size = size;

    return table;
}

void foo( int arr[], int size )
{
    Table* table = createTable( size );

    if( table == NULL )
    {
            printf( "Out of memory" );
            return;
    }

    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            (table->array[i][i]).min = (table->array[i][i]).max = arr[i]; <----------
}
```

I am getting [runtime error](https://ideone.com/wfNBi). When i comment the below two statements, it [runs fine](https://ideone.com/eG949).

```
for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            (table->array[i][i]).min = (table->array[i][i]).max = arr[i]; <----------
```

Why it is showing runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `malloc` of your 2D array `Slot` is wrong:

```
table->array = ( Slot(*)[size] ) malloc( size * size * sizeof( Slot ) );
```

instead of this you should do this:

```
 table->array = (Slot**) malloc(sizeof(Slot*));
   for (int i = 0; i < ArraySizeX; i++)
        table->array[i] = (Slot*) malloc(ArraySizeY*sizeof(Slot));
```

or if you wish to do it in one `malloc` call, however then only have a `Slot*` in your `Table`:

```
table->array = (Slot*) malloc(SizeX * SizeY * Sizeof(Slot));
```

This will allocate your double array properly.

Then also, this construct:

```
  for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
     (table->array[i][i]).min = (table->array[i][i]).max = arr[i];
```

you should really do one assignment at a time:

```
  for( i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i )
  {
      (table->array[i][i]).max = arr[i];
      (table->array[i][i]).min = (table->array[i][i]).max;
  }
```

Comment: How can i allocate memory for 2D array in minimum malloc calls to access it as array[i][j]? Regarding nested loop, i only want to fill the diagonal slots. Thats why i did it using one loop.

Comment: @Aashish ah ok regards the nested loop. I couldn't infer that from your question.   AFAIK that's the only way to fill a 2D array. I don't think it can be done with any less `malloc` calls.

Comment: we can allocate memory for 2D array using single malloc call. I have just checked. Let me know the issues, if any. https://ideone.com/Vxlv5

Comment: @Aashish i stand corrected, I'm sorry. You can do it with one call to `malloc`. I edited my answer.

Comment: no, "only have a Slot* in your Table" won't work. See here: https://ideone.com/PGt2o. It is still giving run-time error. What i have suggested is applicable when to allocate the memory to typecasted pointer. Refer the previous ideone link.

Comment: @Aashish I can't view your ideone links. Please post pastebin or use liveworkspace.org and create link there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16690/discussion-between-aashish-and-tony-the-lion)